# How to access data of an InheritedWidget with pushed routes?

Tags: flutter, dart, inherited-widget

So I have an InheritedWidget which holds a token.

```
class TokenHolder extends InheritedWidget {
  final String token;

  const TokenHolder({@required this.token, @required Widget child})
      : assert(child != null),
        super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TokenHolder oldWidget) => oldWidget.token != token;

  static TokenHolder of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<TokenHolder>();
  }
}
```

Then somewhere high up in my app, I have used it to display `MyScreen`

```
...
builder: (context) {
  ...
  return TokenHolder(
     token: token,
     child: MyScreen(),
  );
}
```

`MyScreen` works as expected. It can get the TokenHolder´s token correctly.

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MYyScreenState createState() => _MYyScreenState ();
}

class _MYyScreenState extends State<MyScreen > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String token = TokenHolder.of(context).token; // This works

    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context, builder: (context) => PushedScreen());
      },
      child: Text(token) // This works
    );
  }
}
```

However, `PushedScreen` seems to return `null` when we call `TokenHolder.of(context)`. Why is this? Why cannot the TokenHolder be found?

```
class PushedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PushedScreenState createState() => _PushedScreenState ();
}

class _PushedScreenState extends State<PushedScreen > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String token = TokenHolder.of(context).token; // DOES NOT WORK -> null.token

    return Text(token);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the token using "TokenHolder.of(context).token", you could pass the `token` as an `argument` when you push the route. (I don't know if it's required to use pushNamed, but that's what I use)

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/pushedScreen', 
    arguments: token
);
```

Then to get the `token` in PushedScreen either use:

```
MaterialApp(
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) { 
        //only needed if their are multiple screens
        if (settings.name == '/pushedScreen') {
            String token = settings.arguments;
        } 
    }
    
)
```

You can also try (within pushedScreen)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String token = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
}
```

To use pushNamed:

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes {
        '/': (context) => ARoute(),
        '/pushedScreen': (context) => PushedScreen(),
    }
)
```

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a simple solution, but the whole point of using InheritedWidget is avoid passing props down to every child. My `PushedRoute` pushes a new route, which needs the token, so this is not the solution I am after.